# Primefaces <p:inplace> text fields populated with Strings from ArrayList, not updating in table with Ajax save

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable with `<p:inplace>` and `<p:inputText>` that I populate with Strings from an ArrayList. After updating the value, I'm not able to save it, it just reverts back to it's original value.

Here is the xhtml:

```
<p:panel styleClass="center" id="opPanel">
    <h:outputText value="Add Operations" />
    <p:dataTable id="ops" value="#{editServiceBean.ops}" var="op">
        <p:column headerText="Operations">
            <p:inplace editor="true" emptyLabel="">
                 <p:inputText id="operations" value="#{op}" />
                 <p:ajax event="save" update="dataForm:opPanel, dataForm:edit, dataForm:ops, ops:operations" />
            </p:inplace>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:panel>
```

"ops" is just an `ArrayList` of Strings, so the var "op" is just one of the Strings.

Comment: What does the list #{editServiceBean.ops} return? List of ops Objects or Strings or?

Comment: @Emil Kaminski it returns a list of Strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a list of Strings in this example. Strings are immutable, which results in that the inputText cannot set the value on your item.

Create a wrapper class containing the String as your itemslist.